# I need to take a variable in Lua which stores its previous value every time the program runs again

Tags: function, loops, lua

eg. If I run the code and suppose  my variable has value 5, then if it runs again it should take the value 5 and start running again. Suggest some way please

Comment: Store it in a file, and load from it.

Comment: Is the questions about how to get the value stored, or is it about how to get the value stored upon it the program exiting or the value changing?

Comment: Which program runs again? The host program (in C) or the Lua program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a closure:

```
local yourFunc = (function()
    local someVar = 5
    return function()
        print( someVar )
    end
end)()
```